# Type from node_modules is unknown when targeting ES6 with compiler API

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at some code with the [TypeScript Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) and I've come across a strange scenario where imports that are resolved from `node_modules` are unknown as a type only when targeting ES6/ES2015.

Setup:

```
npm install --save typescript
```

Code looking at:

```
// fileToAnalyze.ts
import * as ts from "typescript";

let myVar: ts.Node;
```

Code to run:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as path from "path";

function runWithTarget(name: string, target: ts.ScriptTarget) {
  const program = ts.createProgram([path.join(__dirname, "fileToAnalyze.ts")], { target });
  const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
  const file = program.getSourceFiles().filter(f => /fileToAnalyze/.test(f.fileName))[0];

  const statement = (file.statements[1] as ts.VariableStatement);
  const node = statement.declarationList.declarations[0];
  const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);

  console.log(`${name}: ${typeChecker.typeToString(type)}`);
}

runWithTarget("ES5", ts.ScriptTarget.ES5); // outputs Node
runWithTarget("ES6", ts.ScriptTarget.ES6); // outputs any
```

I could spend a few days figuring this out for myself, but I know some very knowledgeable people on here can help me find the answer sooner. Why does this happen and how can I get the type of the variable in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the module resolution changes by default from `ts.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs` to `ts.ModuleResolutionKind.Classic` when targeting ES6.

This can be fixed by forcing a module resolution of `ts.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs` by specifying that in the compiler options.

Comment: I only realized this when looking at this function in [*program.ts*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7173fa8d024d6a251d5b4f3c4a24b0b8adc4f12f/src/compiler/program.ts#L290).