# Analyze javascript file using Typescript Compiler

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Refer to: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API, I want to get **type of node** in AST.

It is successful for `angular` project because it is written using typescript and `tsconfig.json` exists.

When I try to analyze `react app` which is written using javascript

```
const program = ts.createProgram({
    rootNames: [fileName],
    options: {
        strict: true,
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
        allowJs: true,
        checkJs: true
    }
})
const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
... ...
```

I get: `typechecker.getTypeAtLocation(node).getSymbol()` is `undefined`.

I assume `options` of `ts.createProgram` is wrong.

Comment: I think `typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node)` might be returning the `error` type. Are there any diagnostics returned by `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the option: `moduleResolution: ts.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs` is key.

```
const program = ts.createProgram({
    rootNames: [file1],
    options: {
        strict: true,
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
        allowJs: true,
        checkJs: true,
        moduleResolution: ts.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs
    }
})
```

The above works for React JS.

Comment: For some background, this solution depends on the scenario and the reason this occurs is because when targeting ES2015 or above, the default module resolution will change from `NodeJs` to `Classic`. So this isn't because a JS file was being analyzed and what you were probably getting was the `unknown` type. Read more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37619561/188246).